# How can I get the relative path of the current director up to an arbitrary parent dir?

Tags: terraform

This is not a module just a workspace.

Folder structure:

```
workspace1
    - workspace2
    - workspace3
        - workspace4
    - workspace5
```

If I CD into workspace for the full path is: `/Users/me/my-files/terraform/workspace1/workspace3/workspace4`

How can I use terraform functions to be able to get just the path `workspace1/workspace3/workspace4`

Is there a way I can get the full path (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/abspath.html) and then trim out everything before workspace1? perhaps replace() can do that? There are many more features in the latest TF version though I want to check there isn't a feature that makes this easy I could not find in the docs.

```
# trying to use capture groups doesn't seem to work (just outputs full path)
locals {
  test = replace(
    abspath(path.root),
    "/(.*)(workspace1.*)",
    "$2"
  )
}
output "test" { value = "${local.test}"
```

### Edit

This match should work but it's not supported:

```
      test = replace(
        abspath(path.root),
        "/.+?(?=workspace1)/",
        "$1"
unsupported Perl syntax: `(?=`.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming there aren't any complications like symlinks to make the problem more "interesting", perhaps you could do it by using `abspath` both on `path.module` and on a relative path from there to your codebase root and then use the length of the latter to trim the former. For example:

```
locals {
  module_path        = abspath(path.module)
  codebase_root_path = abspath("${path.module}/../..")

  # Trim local.codebase_root_path and one additional slash from local.module_path
  module_rel_path    = substr(local.module_path, length(local.codebase_root_path)+1, length(local.module_path))
}
```

In the above I'm assuming that the current module is two nesting levels under the codebase root, and using that to discover the absolute path of the codebase root in order to trim it off the absolute module path.

Answer (score 1):

This works I think i had the syntax wrong:

```
#Folder structure
#workspace1
#    - workspace2
#    - workspace3
#        - workspace4
#    - workspace5

#abs path on disk: /Users/me/my-files/terraform/workspace1/workspace3/workspace4

locals {
  test = replace(
    abspath(path.root),
    "/.+?(workspace1.*)/",
    "$1"
  )
}
output "test" { value = "${local.test}" }
```